Looking for appropriate model to run on SPSS while accounting for multiple measurements on same subject
I have two groups (Group A and Group B) that have different baseline characteristics. All subjects go through 5 different weights (twice each) and an outcome variable is measured. The table below outlines the study design if my explanation is not clear.



Specimen
Group
0 lb
5 lb
10 lb
15 lb
20 lb




#1 Trial 1
A







#1 Trial 2
A







#2 Trial 1
A







#2 Trial 2
A







#3 Trial 1
B







#3 Trial 2
B







#4 Trial 1
B







#4 Trial 2
B








I would like to know:

Does the change in the outcome variable across the 5 weights differ depending on the group (A or B)? In other words is there an interaction effect? I would also like to know the main effects of group and weights.

How to account for the fact that each specimen underwent the same weight twice. Putting each subject through each condition twice was a way to increase our sample size as it is difficult to get specimens for this type of study. Do I input them as separate specimens into SPSS when entering the data or am I required to correlate them in any way since it's the same specimen?


I imagine it would be a linear mixed model but I'm less clear about how to handle question 2.
Thanks in advance.

You have a couple of options:

Average the multiple measurements per specimen per weight and if you have the same number of specimens in each group, use the repeated measures univariate ANOVA command specifying your two main effects and the interaction.
If in addition you want to test for a linear or quadratic effect in the weights, option 1 will also output the test though with an interaction it will be harder to interpret.
Use whatever mixed model routine in SPSS that you like. Specimen is your random effect and everything else is the same. If you enter weight as a numeric variable, the interaction will test a difference in the linear weight trend across groups. In this case, do not average the multiple measurements per weight per specimen.

I use R for mixed models so I’m not sure what SPSS outputs for mixed models but you should be able to easily find other resources on that.
